# VSTS vs Trello - Workflow

Tags: azure-devops, workflow, trello

We are currently using Trello to manage our workflow, however some of the developers want to change to VSTS and others want to stay with trello.

Can one give any insight as to what product is best?

Comment: This is primarily opinion based and isn't a good question for this forum. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is based on your requirement, if current system meet your requirement and you don’t have the time to learn and transform to other product, you can use current product, otherwise I recommend you to learn VSTS and check with your requirement.

Regarding VSTS, there are many features, such as **code manage** (Git and TFVC) that can track changes, review code etc...; **build and release system** that you can verify project and deploy if needed; **Package Management** that you can manage the packages like Nuget.org. Also there are **Scrum, Agile and CMMI process templates** that can meet to different management workflow.